# ListView Crashes application

Tags: android, google-maps, android-listview

Please, I've been trying to add ListView to the android app am developing but it always starts and then crashes when I add the ListView. I need help. I've tried googling for help but found none. I don't know why its not working. Below is my MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
  private GoogleMap maap;
  static final String[] OptionS = new String[]{"for 1","for 2","for 3","for 4"};
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    ListView listView= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                              int position, long id) {
        // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                       ((TextView) view).getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }
    });

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getApplicationContext());
    maap = ((SupportMapFragment)      getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
      .getMap();
    maap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
    maap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
    maap.getUiSettings().setAllGesturesEnabled(true);
    CameraPosition Position =new CameraPosition.Builder()
      .target(new LatLng(33.53,10.08))
      .zoom(7.2f)
      .tilt(40)   
      .build();

    CameraUpdate Update = CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(Position);
    maap.moveCamera(Update);
    maap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                     .position(new LatLng(33.53,10.08))
                     .title("TEST")
                     .draggable(true)
                     .snippet("is good"));
  }
  @Override
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    return true;
  }


  @Override
  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
      case R.id.item1: 
        startActivity(new Intent(this, ActivityMenus.class));
      case R.id.item2: 
        startActivity(new Intent(this, ActivityMenus.class));
      case R.id.item3: 
        startActivity(new Intent(this, ActivityMenus.class));
      case R.id.item4: 
        startActivity(new Intent(this, ActivityMenus.class));
    }
    return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: You, and us, need a logcat to know the exact error and solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must call `setContentView()` before trying to use `findViewById()`.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);  // Move me here

    ListView listView= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    // etc
```

Comment: You're welcome, please click the check mark to accept this answer as the solution. (And next time please post the LogCat errors in your question, we might not be able to guess that solution every time...)